# MySQL matching this regex while it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to recognize quoting (citing) somebody's else sentence in a markdown text, which I have in my local copy of MySQL GHTorrent dataset. So I wrote this query:

```
select * from github_discussions where body rlike '(.)*(\s){1,}(>)(\s){1,}(.)+';
```

it matches some unwanted data, which according to https://regex101.com/, it should not with this particular regular expression.

Test string:

```
`Params` is plural -> contain<s>s</s>
```

Matched on MySQL database, not matched at regex101 dot com.

Obvious example of quoting, but not matched at db:

```
Yes, I believe so.\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nK\r\n\r\n> On 19-Jul-2014, at 17:33, Stefan Karpinski <notifications@github.com> wrote:\r\n> \r\n> This is the standard 3-clause BSD license, right?\r\n> \r\n> —\r\n> Reply to this email directly or view it on GitHub.
```

Moreover, MySQL workbench didn't show those return carriage and new line symbols unless copy-pasted here.

Can I normalize (remove \r and \n) with some update query ?

Is MySQL regex implementation different from POSIX standard regex ?
Do you have by any chances maximally clean solution for recognizing quoting in a markdown text ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've got an awful lot of parens in there. Try this as functionally what you have above:

```
select * from github_discussions where body rlike '.*[:blank:]+>[:blank:]+.+'
```

However, I'm not sure that's really what you want.  This would happily match this line:

```
this is before > and after
```

which by my understanding is not a quoted string in markdown. Instead I would anchor it at the beginning like this:

```
select * from github_discussions where body rlike '^[:blank:]*>[:blank:]+'
```

That will match a greater-than sign at the beginning of the line, optionally preceded by whitespace. Is that what you are looking for?

I'm not sure if your data has newlines embedded. If so, you may need to look into ways of having your regex identify newlines using the ^ anchoring symbol.  As is the well accepted conclusion in regex literature, *that is left as an exercise for the student.* :-)